# Spring boot - Using the implementations defined in the other project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependency-injection

I have 2 Projects.

- All the API contract (interfaces) defines in the **demo-parent** project (spring boot application)
- The implementation for those defined in the **demo-child** project (spring boot application)
- **demo-parent** is a dependency for **demo-child**, defined in the pom.xml of **demo-child**

---

In **demo-parent** :

**AccessAPI.java**

```
public interface AccessAPI {
    void call();
}
```

**SpringDemoParentApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDemoParentApplication {

    @Autowired
    private AccessAPI accessAPI;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDemoParentApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void exec() {
        accessAPI.call();
    }
}
```

---

In **demo-child** I have the implementation for the service :

**AccessAPIImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class AccessAPIImpl implements AccessAPI {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        System.out.println("Executing from AccessAPIImpl");
    }
}
```

---

---

**Goal trying to achieve :**
I must be able to build these projects independently, and pass the **demo-child** project jar via classpath to pick the implementation and inject all the implementation when running of **demo-parent** .
Such as :

```
>java -jar demo-parent.jar -cp demo-child.jar
```

I expected that the implementation would be picked up from the **demo-child** and autoinjected but It is not working as expected. 
Note : I dont want to add **demo-child** dependency on **demo-parent**, the implementations/dependency must be picked up at runtime.

---

Please check the Git repository : 
https://github.com/anthonyvk/spring-demo-child 
https://github.com/anthonyvk/spring-demo-parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; TR**:

```
java -cp demo-parent.jar -Dloader.path=demo-child.jar org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

if the demo-child.jar is a Spring Boot application, i.e. if the jar is repacked by the Spring Boot plugin, you need to change the `loader.path`:

```
java -cp demo-parent.jar -Dloader.path='demo-child.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes' org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

**Explanation:**

By default, Spring Boot uses JarLauncher, which looks only in BOOT-INF/lib/ inside the jar archive, `-cp` argument has no effect. The commands above switch to PropertiesLauncher, which honors `loader.path` parameter (`-cp` equivalent). For details see [The Executable Jar Format](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html)

By the way, the project structure seems to be a bit problematic:

- adding spring boot application (demo-parent.jar) as a dependency to demo-child.jar is tricky, as demo-parent.jar is repacked by the Spring Boot plugin and maven cannot find AccessAPI class
- there are runtime circular dependencies, even if not explicitly specified in the POM

I don't know detailed requirements, but if possible, I would suggest:

- extracting interfaces to a separate project, let's say **demo-api**
- making demo-parent and demo-child depended on **demo-api**, not on each other
- making **demo-api** and **demo-child** regular jar's, not Spring Boot applications (removing Spring Boot plugin)

Comment: Thanks Mafor for your response. But the solution did not work. I get the following exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File D:\Workout\Spring\spring-boot-runtime-jar-load-parent\target\'child.jar must exist

Comment: It must be somthing with the path. Is there a '  before child.jar?

Comment: This is what I ran : 
java -cp parent.jar -Dloader.path='child.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes' org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

Comment: I ran with double quotes, I do not see IllegalArgumentException  ::
> java -cp parent.jar -Dloader.path="child.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes" org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

Comment: But I am still getting "Field accessAPI in com.savk.workout.spring.springdemoparent.SpringDemoParentApplication required a bean of type 'com.savk.workout.spring.springdemoparent.AccessAPI' that could not be found."

Comment: Could you extract child.jar and confirm, that your implementation is present under /BOOT-INF/classes ?

Comment: I extracted. The implementation is present inside BOOT-INF/classes

Comment: It's strange. I checked on both, Windows and Linux, and it worked. Is the `AccessAPIImpl` class in the same package (or subpackage) as `SpringDemoParentApplication`?

Comment: Please check the gihub repo : https://github.com/anthonyvk/spring-demo-child  ,  
https://github.com/anthonyvk/spring-demo-parent

Comment: AccessAPIImpl is in Child Project, they cannot be in the same package as SpringDemoParentApplication.

Comment: Well, it will not work that way. You need to either make `springdemochild` a subpackage (not necessarily direct) of the `springdemoparent` or add `@ComponentScan(“com.savk.workout.spring.springdemochild”)` annotation to the `SpringDemoParentApplication`. See [spring-boot-and-component-scan](https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-component-scan)